# Why does TypeScript not report this typing mistake?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following piece of code:

```js
   authUserListener = (next: (newUser: AuthUser) => void, fallback: () => void): Unsubscribe => {
    return this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: firebase.User | null) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.user(user.uid).on("value", (snapshot: firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => {
            const databaseUser = snapshot.val();
            // Merge Auth and Database user
            const mergedUser: UserData = {
              uid: user.uid,
              email: user.email,
              ...databaseUser,
            };
            next(mergedUser);
          },
        );
      } else {
        fallback();
      }
    });
  };
```

This class method is being called like this:

```js
const unsubscribeFromListener = firebase.authUserListener(
      (newUser: UserData) => {
        const different = newUser === user;
        if (different || user === null) {
          setUser(newUser);
        }
      },
      () => {
        if (user !== null) {
          setUser(null);
        }
      },
    );
```

The code works absolutely fine! But, I've noticed that I'm passing a variable of type `UserData` to a function expecting type `AuthUser`. These types are defined as:

```js
type UserData = {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
};

type AuthUser = "uninitialized" | null | UserData;
```

In the `authUserListener` method, I'm calling the `next` function which is passed as a parameter, with a variable of type `UserData` while I said the `authUserListener` receives a function `next` that is of type `(newUser: AuthUser) => void`, so it takes its argument as type `AuthUser`. As you can see above, these two types are not the same. Why isn't TypeScript warning me about the fact that I'm passing the wrong type to the `next` function?

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained [mcve] as described in [ask] so I can drop this into a web IDE like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and demonstrate the issue for myself?  From a glance, it looks like everything is fine... a function of type `(arg: A | B | C) => void` says "I accept `A` or `B` or `C` arguments", so it will be happy to be called with an argument of type `A`.  You should always be able to give a value of a type to someone who accepts a supertype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserData` is a valid type for `AuthUser`. You have created it as `null` or `"uninitialized"` or `UserData`, so any argument that is of type `UserData` is a valid instantiation of a `AuthUser` type.

If you take out the others, your statement is that `type AuthUser = UserData` (or it could be the string literal "uninitialized" or it could be `null`).

If you said that it could be `"3" | "5" | "6"` and you pass in "6", you would expect that to be valid, right? Same thing, you've passed in a valid instance for the type you created.

Does that make it clear?